# OpenCV. Неверно ищет совпадения

Tags: python, opencv

Изображение на котором ищу совпадения.
[image: Изображение на котором ищу]

Шаблон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_arrow():
    img = cv2.imread("screenshot.png") # Картинка с объектом
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Преобразуем в серую
    template = cv2.imread("Screenshot_1.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # Шаблон
    w,h = template.shape[::-1]
     
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    loc = np.where(result >= 0.5)
    # Рисует прямоугольник вокруг объекта
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 200, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("img", img) # Выводит на экран результат
    cv2.waitKey()

def screenshot():
    gameWindow = (300, 100, 1720, 780)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(gameWindow)
    output = im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\screenshot' + '.png', 'PNG')
    print('Скриншот сделан и сохранён')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # time.sleep(3) 
    # screenshot()
    find_arrow()
```

Comment: Используйте cv2.matchTemplate с маской объекта. На скриншоте ведь у вас объект не на белом фоне, как в шаблоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте cv2.matchTemplate с маской объекта. На скриншоте ведь у вас объект не на белом фоне, как в шаблоне. Плюс шаблон у вас с альфа-каналом, его и можно сделать маской.
Измененная функция:

```
def find_arrow():
    img = cv2.imread("screenshot.jpg") # Картинка с объектом
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Преобразуем в серую
    template = cv2.imread("Screenshot_1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    mask=template[:,:,3] # извлекаем альфа-канал как маску 
    template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY) # серый шаблон
    w,h = template.shape[::-1]
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_img, template,  cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, mask=mask)
    loc = np.where(result >= 0.55) # подбираем порог
    # Рисует прямоугольник вокруг объекта
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 200, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("img", img) # Выводит на экран результат
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, ваше сообщение не тянет на ответ. Оформите его как комментарий к вопросу, а этот "ответ" удалите.